# Unable to connect to the signalr hub when it is hosted in webserver

Tags: signalr

im bugged up with a issue in SignalR and breaking my head for the past 10 days.

I have the hub as a self host in a console application. It works fine when it is hosted in the local system as follows

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:8080/signalr';
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.start()
.done(function () { alert("Now connected!"); })
.fail(function () { alert("Could not Connect!"); });
```

The problem is when i host it in the server and try to access the hub url as

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://www.domainname.com:8080/signalr';
```

it always says could not connect.

if i browse the page in the server machine and try to connect the hub as localhost it works fine but unable to connect as domainname

i have done all the steps.

1. Added the port 8080 in the firewall
2. I have run the console app as admin
3. in the console app, i have given the server url as *:8080

please help me. im breaking my head now. is there anything that i need to enable in the server. the server is windows 2008 R2

Comment: I have even run this command in DOS using the admin rights -- 
    netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=Everyone

Comment: So you have + in url acl but you're using * in your code. Try using either + everywhere or * everywhere.

Comment: yes i have updated it with * every where and its still not working

Comment: did you check the requests in fiddler or firebug? also make sure that the port 8080 is not used by other apps

Comment: im getting this message in fiddler 

[Fiddler] The socket connection to www.domain.com failed. <br />ErrorCode: 10060. <br />A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: it worked when i changed the port to 80